# Dropdown: after submit, do an operation and show result on different page with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Hi there fellow coders,

I am a bit new in JavaScript and I need some help.I try explain what I want to do.

I have a dropdown after a dropdown is selected, and a button is clicked a simple operation should start and show the result on a different page.

Now, I created an alert which shows a value but I want to show this value on a different landing page using html and javascript.
Here is what it looks right now:

http://test-kk.bitballoon.com/

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" 
      id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="name@example.com">
 </div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Bitte wählen sie ihre 
Krankenkasse</label>
<select class="form-control" id="mySelect">
    <option value=" Ihr Eigenanteil: 33 €">Actimonda</option>
    <option value=" Ihr Eigenanteil: 33 €">AOK Bayern</option>
    <option value=" Ihr Eigenanteil: 33 €">AOK Hessen</option>
    <option value=" Ihr Eigenanteil: 33 €">AOK Niedersachsen</option>
    <option value=" Ihr Eigenanteil: 33 €">AOK Nordost</option>
    <option value=" Ihr Eigenanteil: 33 €">AOK NORDWEST</option>
    <option value=" Ihr Eigenanteil: 33 €">AOK PLUS</option>
  </select>
  <button type="button"  onclick="myFunction()">Hier Klicken</button>
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Try to use `locaStorage.setItem` to save it and `localStorage.getItem` to retrieve it on next page.

Comment: you can save the value in cookies and retrieve the value on next page

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't know how to implement this: How do I have to change the code...I think I need a more detailed explanation....I'm new to this kind of problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 get the value on this page

```
var val = document.getElementById('mySelect').value;
```

2 save it into localStorage

```
localStorage.setItem("selectedoption", val);
```

3 retrieve the value on next page

```
var savedVal = localStorage.getItem("selectedoption");
```

Alternatively, you can use `cookie` or `sessionStorage` Object too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't know how to implement this: How do I have to change the code...Now when I click the button the alert pops...but It should send the user to another page and shows the specific <option value ...>. How and where do I set your 3 steps? (In my exmaple the values are all the same strings for now..I will change that later.)

Comment: add 1 & 2 into your `myFunction` such as after or before `alert`. Add 3 into next page. To send user to next page use such as ` window.location.assign(newPage)`

Comment: ok ,thank you very much...now I get to a new page and on this page the alert opens and shows the value....Now the last thing I want to achieve: I don't want to show the value as an alert. I want it to "show" up on the page --- how can I do that...can I replace the alert with another expression...

Comment: thank you for the really good help...it works with document.write(savedVal); instead of alert...